# How to get specific files with lftp batch file

Tags: bash, get, sftp, lftp

I'm actually trying to get all files beginning with the current date from another server with SFTP. Nevertheless, `*` does not work in SFTP so I don't see how I can do...

Here is the batch I've done so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://name@server
get $today*
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

@Martin Prikryl

Thank you, it works fine now.
I've search a bit before you answered and I've found this (a lot less efficient^^):

```
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
var=`echo `echo ls -1 | sftp name@domain:dir1/subdir` | sed -n 's/ /\n/gp'|sed -n '/^$today/p'`
lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://name@server
get $var
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `mget` instead of the `get`.

See https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

> **get**
>   ...
>   Does not expand wildcards,  use `mget` for that.
>   ...
>   **mget**
>   ...
>   Gets selected files with expanded **wildcards**.